# How would I use jmeter to loop through a list of GET calls with ID's returned from database?

Tags: for-loop, jmeter

I'm trying to use jmeter to loop through a list of unique ID's returned from a basic query like the one below

```
select ID from blah order by asc;
```

currently, the only solution I know to use is to create a HTTP Request for each individual ID, which would be very time consuming as there are currently 70+ unique ID's. I'm sure there's a way to use a for-loop to cycle through whatever the query returns, and insert each result into the URL so I can also save myself from having to update and add another HTTP Request every time they add a new ID.

any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

1. Define a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name which will hold the IDs returned by the SQL query under `Variable Names` section of the [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler - basically put a meaningful name there, i.e. `ID`

   [image: JMeter JDBC Variable Name]
2. This way JMeter will create a set of variables like:

   ```
   ID_1=foo
   ID_2=bar
   ID_3=baz
   ...
   ```

   You can see all the generated values using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination:

   [image: JMeter Variables from JDBC]

   See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide for more information on working with the JDBC test elements results
3. Once you have this form of `ID` variables you can use then in the [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) like:

   [image: JMeter Foreach Controller]
4. Then add a **single** sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller and refer the ID as `${CURRENT_ID}` - JMeter will iterate through all extracted IDs

   [image: JMeter iterate IDs from SQL]

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you! this helped me figure out a better way to set up several of the tests I've already created.

Comment: how can we extand this to more than one variable, to process a whole row of variables at one ?

Comment: This really help me save lot of time. It explains with screenshots which is nice.